# how to strip extra spaces of values of elements in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to strip out spaces in the values of element.

Source:

```
   <sss>
      HI:
      HELLO:
      HOW:
    </sss>
```

Output:

```
    <sss>HI:HELLO:HOW
```

I have tried this

```
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

but it's not affecting the output.

Comment: What does your current XSLT look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to strip a character or more then use translate listing the character(s) as the second argument and the empty string as the third `translate(., ' ', '')` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="sss">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(), ' ', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In order to get the result with all white-space removed, use the standard XPath [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function**:

```
translate(., ' &#xA;&#xD;&#xC;&#9;', '')
```

It *isn't necessary* to use `normalize-space()` at all.

**The template needed for this whitespace elimination is simply this**:

```
<xsl:template match="sss/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' &#xA;&#xD;&#9;', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The complete transformation includes also the identity rule, so that if the XML document contains non-`sss` elements, these will be copied "as-is":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="sss/text()">
     <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' &#xA;&#xD;&#xC;&#9;', '')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the reference to #xC is only well formed if you are using XML 1.1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Good observation -- I must have been still sleeping this morning :)